# My bashrc file has a comma in it

Tags: filenames, git-bash

My bashrc file is listed like this when viewed in the file explorer:

```
,bashrc
```

I believe the filename should be formatted like this:

```
.bashrc
```

1. Will the comma affect how the program runs?
2. Is it ok to replace the comma with a period?

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work):

> .bashrc is a shell script that Bash runs whenever it is started
>   interactively.

The `.bashrc` file must start with a period, not a comma, as it's a "hidden" file.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) regarding hidden files:

> In computing, a hidden folder (sometimes hidden directory) or hidden
>   file is a folder or file which filesystem utilities do not display by
>   default when showing a directory listing. They are commonly used for
>   storing user preferences or preserving the state of a utility, and are
>   frequently created implicitly by using various utilities.

Before renaming the file (replacing the comma with a period) you should first read it's contents and make sure that there is nothing potentially harmful there.

Someone could have potentially changed the period to a comma to ensure that the file isn't run while making risky or temporary changes.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan.  That's good to know.  When you say that the file is "hidden", do you mean that files with a period are hidden?

Comment: Yep. I added a little more content regarding hidden files in my answer

Comment: That's an excellent explanation.  One more question- how do I read the file to make sure everything is OK before renaming the file with the period at the start?

Comment: Well, I suppose it greatly depends on the contents of the file, and how long it is. For example, if you see a bunch of `rm`'s in there then it's removing files which could be harmful :) . Other than that, if you have access to whoever originally wrote the file, it would be good to ask them why they named it using the comma

Comment: I opened up the file in Notepad, and here were the contents: "alias gpo="git push origin"
alias gco="git checkout"
alias gs="git status"
alias gfa="git fetch --all"
That's it.  So, I think it will be alright if I change it back.  Thanks for helping out a beginner!

Comment: Yes, that does seem safe after a quick glance